# How to install Frama-c on a computer without internet connection

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, frama-c

I am trying to install Frama-c on a computer which can not connect to the internet because of the security but I can copy needed files to this computer using USB. The current operating system of this computer is Windows. 
However, I had some problems when trying to install Frama-c on Windows and in the homepage of Frama-c, they say that currently Windows isn't officially supported by Frama-c team. So I think it is better to install Frama-c on Ubuntu. Then I used Oracle VM Virtual box to install Ubuntu. Note that when I was installing Ubuntu I didn't have the internet connection, so I didn't install third-party software.
Now I want to ask is it possible to install Frama-c in this case? If yes, what are files needed and where can I get them?

Comment: Note that Ubuntu 16.04 is quite old at this point (the latest LTS is currently 18.04) and that can cause some minor additional issues. Also, `docker` may be an alternative: the `ocaml/opam` docker image already has internet configured, so doing `opam install depext; opam depext frama-c; opam install frama-c` is enough to get Frama-C installed (you may need to `sudo apt-get update` before). This requires internet connection but should be configured by default. I do not know the details about forwarding X to Windows, however, to ensure you have access to the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `opam` installed on a machine with an internet connection, it should be possible to use [`opam-bundle`](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/opam-bundle/), which is meant to create a `.tar.gz` archive containing all the **ocaml** dependencies necessary to install a given package.

Note however that **system** dependencies (in the case of Frama-C gmp and gtk C libraries) are apparently not included, so that unless they are included in the iso you have used to install Ubuntu, you will need to retrieve them separately.

Finally, note that `opam` is available on windows, at https://fdopen.github.io/opam-repository-mingw/installation/ and should let you install Frama-C on windows.